# Xcode iPhone SDK (5.x) - Accessing a NSString inside AppDelegate

Tags: delegates, declared-property

I want to access a `NSString` from `AppDelegate.m` that is located inside `ViewController.m`.

I have a *Single View Application*, and i want to save my `NSString` using `applicationDidEnterBackground:` inside `AppDelegate.m`.

The `NSString` is located inside `ViewController.m`, and is not declared in `AppDelegate.m`.

I tried to declare it in `AppDelegate.h` and then access it in the `ViewController.m` (And reversed).

`ViewController.h`:

```
@interface MyAppViewController : UIViewController {
    NSString *MyString;
}
```

`AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
   NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [defaults setObject:MyString forKey:@"SavedString"];
   [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register MyAppViewController to observer UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(goToBackground:) 
        name:@"UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification"
        object:nil];
```

and in the method `goToBackground` you can save in NSUserDefaults the `MyString`.

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables in one class are not available to methods of a different class.  You can expose an interface to get and set instance variables from outside a class by either defining getter and setter methods, or by defining properties (which are essentially syntactic sugar for getter and setter methods.  See the [Declared Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) chapter of The Objective-C Programming Language for details.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if MyString belongs to the MyAppViewController object, you at the very least need a reference to the controller. Assume you call it `controller`.

Then, if you want MyString to be accessible as a property to other classes, you have to declare it as such:

```
@interface MyAppViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *MyString;
@end
```

Then in your app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:controller.MyString forKey:@"MyString"]; //<-- This is where it all goes wrong. MyString is shown as undeclared identifier.
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Also as a side note, you might want to double check your naming conventions for clarity.